# About finite $p$-group finitely generated.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $p$ a prime number. Let $G$ be a $p$-group finitely generated, say, $G = \left<x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m \right>$. Denote by $\gamma_i(G)$ the $ith$ term of the lower central series of $G$. Then, is true that $\gamma_i(G)$ is generated by a number of elements that depends only $m$ and $i$?

Comment: In general, we have that if $G$ is a nilpotent and finitely generated group then, all subgroups of $G$ there are finitely generated. More, if $G = \left<x_1, \ldots, x_m \right>$ is finitely generated then $\gamma_i(G)$ is the normal closure  of the subgroup of $G$ generated by all the commutators in the form $[b_1, \ldots, b_i]$, where $b_j \in \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}, 1 \leq j \leq i$. But even with this information I could not still conclude my question is whether true or not.

Comment: You may want to check here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40985/bound-for-the-rank-of-a-nilpotent-group  , The nilpotency class $\,c\,$ seems to be key in this problem, but of course you can always argue that $\,c\le m\,$ ...

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite?

Comment: I'm not sure whom your asking, @DerekHolt, but the OP's title states "finite p-group"

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes. I supose $G$ a finite group.

Comment: @DonAntonio. Because I can assume that $c \leq m$?

Comment: We have by hypothesis $G$ is a $p$-group (then is nilpotent). So, we have that the quotient $\gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ is (finitely) generated by a function that dependent only $i$ and $m$ (because $G$ is $m$-generated). How $G$ is nilpotent, then really exists $c$ that $\gamma_{c+1}(G) = 1$. Then, we have that for all $i \leq c$ then $\gamma_i(G)$ is generated by a number of elements that depends only $i$ and $m$ (because the class of finitely generated groups is closed to a extention). And, for $i > c$ we have that $\gamma_i(G) = 1$. I asking: This argument is true?

Comment: @AgenorAndrade, did you ask me *why* can you assume $\,c\le m\,$ ? If you did: because of a simple inductive argument and taking into account that a group of order $\,p^n\,$ has , for any $\,0\le k\le n\,$, a *normal* subgroup of order $\,p^k\,$ (and thus we can go to quotients and etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no. Let $G$ be a wreath product of a cyclic group of order $p$ with a cyclic group of order $p^k$. Then the derived group $\gamma_2(G)$ is elementary abelian of rank $p^k-1$. There is of course a bound as a function of $m$, $i$ and the nilpotency class $c$.